# Make use of XPath Axes to extract sibling elements' text

Tags: xpath

Given the following html, how to get a list of tuple (TIME, COMMENT, OOXX) by XPath? I think I need to make use of **XPath Axes** but not sure how to use that. Furthermore, the **OOXX** seems not to belong to any tags!

```
<div class="contents">
  <p></p>
  <div class="meta">TIME</div>OOXX
  <div class="comment">COMMENT</div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="meta">TIME</div>OOXX
  <div class="comment">COMMENT</div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="meta">TIME</div>OOXX
  <div class="comment">COMMENT</div>
  <p></p>
  <div class="meta">TIME</div>OOXX
  <div class="comment">COMMENT</div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you'll want to deal with multiple such tuples in the input XML will depend on your requirements and the facilities of the context of the XPath evaluation.

However, here's how to get the first TIME:

```
/div/div[@class="meta"][1]/text()
```

Here's how to get the first COMMENT:

```
/div/div[@class="comment"][1]/text()
```

And here's how to get the first OOXX:

```
/div/div[@class="meta"][1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```